# usbmon for Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, sniffing

I want to analyze usb communication out of my device: SGS4. 
I see everywhere that the usbmon is needed to be configured and compiled into the kernel. Afaik, this module is not built in the android linux system.

I don't have much experience in compiling a kernel but if this is necessary I would do it.

Can you tell what are the steps of doing so? i.e. how to compile the linux kernel for android such that it would include the usbmon module.

Comment: It might be easier to do it on the other side, unless your device is acting as an USB host. You'll find Android quite a bit different from "normal" Linux, so doing it yourself if you don't have experience will be painful. You might get some 3rd party firmware (mod) that supports usbmon.

Comment: It's not the porting which is a challenge, but having access to flash & execute a custom kernel at all.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you have access to:

- the sources of the **version of Linux currently running on your device**. It could be available on [Samsung repository](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=GT-I9500) if you haven't changed the ROM. Or some custom kernels if you use an alternative ROM (CyanogenMod, Clockwork, ...).
- an **ARM toolchain** that is proven suited to compile this kernel.
- **the version of AOSP** currently running on your device (e.g. 4.1.2). You need it to build the new `boot.img` out of the newly compiled kernel image `zImage`.

You need to enable `CONFIG_USB_MON` in linux:

```
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=your/armeabi/toolchain/path menuconfig
```

type `/` to search then enter `USB_MON`. The flag is located in:

```
-> Device Drivers
  -> USB support (USB_SUPPORT [=n])
    -> Support for Host-side USB (USB [=n])
```

Then rebuild:

```
$ make CROSS_COMPILE=your/armeabi/toolchain/path zImage
```

Then **please read** `Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt` directly from your kernel sources.
It should teach you everything you need to know.

Comment: Can I compile the usbmon module seperately and load it without compiling the entire kernel?

Comment: To do so, you need to have your kernel sources anyway. Do you have the sources of the kernel currently running on your device? Did you succeed to compile it with its current configuration? You'll go nowhere without these two prerequisites...

Comment: @Bush: Well, separate compilation is not an option in this case - if the kernel was built with USBMON option set to N, as opposed to M, some hooks (usb_mon_register, et al.) will be missing. You will have to rebuild the kernel even if the you are going to build it as module.