# sniffing USB transactions between android phone and HID device

Tags: android, usb, reverse-engineering, hid, usb-otg

I have a device and its driver for android. Device connects to android phone via OTG cable and uses HID interface for communicating.

I need to write similar driver for PC. Are there any possibilities for sniff USB transactions in that case? Is it possible to penetrate into OTG cable, connect it to the PC and sniff on the PC using wireshark or something else? [image: scheme] What should i add to the scheme above to get it worked?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24117094

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a hardware USB protocol analyzer such as the [Beagle USB 12](https://www.totalphase.com/products/beagle-usb12/).